# DIV based layout - bg and buttons relative to screen

Tags: html, css, background, css-position

I'm just working on a simple HTML page but still struggling with the divs.
The plan is: a fullscreen background and four horizontal buttons next to each other on the bottom. The buttons are currently mapped to the background image - so I could just add four invisible layers (divs) with some hrefs for example. Otherwise I would add them manually (in four single jpgs) to the bottom...

Howsoever, I want the whole site to (borderlessly) scale up and down to variable screen resolutions. Therefore also the sizes of the divs/images should scale equally and keep its position.

What I've got so far:

```css
 body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 .background {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 img {
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="background">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="background.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

At this point I only have the background set up: its in an img-div within a background container with absolute positioning.

How could I add the four buttons now to stick at the bottom of the background a keep its relative size and position when the screen resolution changes?

:)

Comment: Can you please create fiddle?

Comment: Please show us a fiddle of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the button images out of the background image, set the body rules as follows (with background-image), add a div at the bottom and put the buttons in there (I chose DIVs with background-images for the buttons, but of course you can also use `<button>` tags. Adjust the "bottom" and button heights and the button margins as needed:

CSS

```
body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: url(background.jpg) center center fixed;
   background-size: cover
 }
 .bottom {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 50px;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
 }
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
 }
.button1 {
   background: url(button1.jpg) center center fixed;
   background-size: cover
}
.button2 {
   background: url(button2.jpg) center center fixed;
   background-size: cover
}
.button3 {
   background: url(button3.jpg) center center fixed;
   background-size: cover
}
.button4 {
   background: url(button4.jpg) center center fixed;
   background-size: cover
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
   (your content)
</div>
  <div class="bottom">
   <div class="button button1">(button text 1...)</div>
   <div class="button button2">(button text 2...)</div>
   <div class="button button3">(button text 3...)</div>
   <div class="button button4">(button text 4...)</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick help!

The code looks good so far. But I still have the problem that the buttons change its size when I rise or decrease the screen resolution. Is there a way to give them fixed sizes in relation to the whole screen? "buttonX" should always have x% of the screens width and x% of its height... And I don't want the actual visible positioning resp. margin to change when the resolution changes :/

But many thanks so for!

Comment: you can use pixel or percent as unit for any size/margin/border etc. The only thing about percentage values is that they need to be able to relate to a parent element (= surrounding container) with a defined size, so that the browser can calculate that percentage. (BTW, since you are new at Stack Overflow: Your "answer" should rather be written as a comment to my answer, not as a new answer to your own question)

Comment: Sorry for that :P

I have fixed the issue with percent values now, thx.